# Can't Get Microsoft Teams Basic Personal Tab to Work

Tags: microsoft-teams

Went through all of the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-and-run and repeated it for the letter. I can get my tab to show up in the browser but when I sideload the app into Teams, add it, and go to the Personal tab it just remains blank. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot for the same. That will be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like the validDomains section in the manifest might be incomplete. See here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

Comment: @Ashby Utting Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @Ashby Utting,Did you add the domain in validDomain[] array in the manifest?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, could you move your comments as an answer for better visibility?

Comment: sure, done it now

Comment: @Saonti-MSFT Yes, I currently have localhost:3000 in my list of validDomains.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the validDomains section in the manifest might be incomplete, as this is a typical reason why the tab doesn't display. See here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

Comment: Yes, I currently have localhost:3000 in my list of validDomains.

Comment: I don't think Teams allows localhost addresses. You should rather use a tunneling tool like ngrok. Much of the Teams documentation refers to it for exactly this reason. See here for instance : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/quickstarts/create-personal-tab-node-yeoman#establish-a-secure-tunnel-to-your-tab . In this case, the ngrok address would be what you use in the validDomains (e.g. "abc123.ngrok.io")